# How to annotate and combine some fields using Django annotate ORM?

Tags: django

I have a product table with 2 fields:

| Name | Tag |
| --- | --- |
| A | 12 |
| B | 13 |

I want to fetch the rows annotating and adding a field type, which is a list , `type=[1,2]`, such that I get the output as:

| Name | Tag | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 12 | 1 |
| B | 13 | 1 |
| A | 12 | 2 |
| B | 13 | 2 |

What should the query be to get the desired result?

The query should be `Product.objects.annotate(type=?)`